# Read txt files with single column, record in several rows each row a cell, into a tidy dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data in a text file

```
RecordID:Name1
VariableA:14
VariableB: 34
VariableC: 21
VariableD:red
VariableE: low
RecordID: Name2
VariableA: 31
VariableB: 21
VariableD:yellow
VariableE:high
```

and so on, several thousands records.

Each record starts then with a RecordID: and an identifier
Occasionally some variable data is missing like in second record there is no Variable D. Also sometimes a variable cell can span accross two rows when a text string is split. Therefore I cannot rely on row numbers only on Variable names.

How to read such data into an R in a tidy form in columns:

```
RecordID | VariableA | VariableB | Variable C | Variable D| Variable E
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Name1       14           34           21           red        low
Name2       31           21                        yellow     high
```

Comment: Related: [*Convert data with one column and multiple rows into multi column multi row data*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44795372/2204410)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). Assuming that the data frame in the original format is `dat`. `dat2` is the final output. Notice that to create `dat` by using the `read.table` command, we can specify `sep = :` to read in the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate_all(funs(str_trim(.))) %>%            # Trim the white space for all columns
  mutate(RecordID = ifelse(V1 %in% "RecordID", 
                           V2, NA)) %>%        # Create a new column with the name from V2 when V1 is RecordID
  fill(RecordID) %>%                           # Fill in NA in the RecordID column  
  filter(!V1 %in% "RecordID") %>%              # Remove V1 == "RecordID"
  spread(V1, V2, convert = TRUE)               # Spread the data frame
dat2
#   RecordID VariableA VariableB VariableC VariableD VariableE
# 1    Name1        14        34        21       red       low
# 2    Name2        31        21        NA    yellow      high
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "RecordID:Name1
VariableA:14
                  VariableB: 34
                  VariableC: 21
                  VariableD:red
                  VariableE: low
                  RecordID: Name2
                  VariableA: 31
                  VariableB: 21
                  VariableD:yellow
                  VariableE:high", sep = ":", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

This file is in DCF format so another option could be to read it directly using `read.dcf`

```
#read text file
txt <- readLines("test.txt")

#insert a blank line before each line having "RecordID" so that the subsequent line is identified as a new record
record_num <- grep("RecordID", txt)
for (i in seq(length(record_num))) {
  txt <- append(txt, "", after = grep("RecordID", txt)[i] - 1)
}

#now read dcf file and convert it to a dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(txt)))
```

**Output is:**

```
> df
  RecordID VariableA VariableB VariableC VariableD VariableE
1    Name1        14        34        21       red       low
2    Name2        31        21      <NA>    yellow      high
```

**Sample data:**
`test.txt` contains

```
RecordID:Name1
VariableA:14
VariableB: 34
VariableC: 21
VariableD:red
VariableE: low
RecordID: Name2
VariableA: 31
VariableB: 21
VariableD:yellow
VariableE:high
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

```
library(tidyr)

xy <- readLines(con = "test.txt") # this is your data file, read it line-wise

out <- data.frame(temp = xy)
find.record <- grepl("RecordID:", out$temp) # identify where record starts

# create RecordID column
out$RecordID <- NA
out[find.record, "RecordID"] <- as.character(out[find.record, "temp"])
out <- fill(out, "RecordID")
out$RecordID <- trimws(sapply(strsplit(out$RecordID, ":"), "[[", 2))

# now that we have a RecordID column, remove these lines
out <- out[!find.record, ]

# split the data on colon and put into respective columns
out$variable <- trimws(sapply(strsplit(as.character(out$temp), ":"), "[[", 1))
out$value <- trimws(sapply(strsplit(as.character(out$temp), ":"), "[[", 2))
out$temp <- NULL # remove temporary data
out

   RecordID  variable  value
2     Name1 VariableA     14
3     Name1 VariableB     34
4     Name1 VariableC     21
5     Name1 VariableD    red
6     Name1 VariableE    low
8     Name2 VariableA     31
9     Name2 VariableB     21
10    Name2 VariableD yellow
11    Name2 VariableE   high

# transform from long to wide format
spread(out, key = variable, value = value)

  RecordID VariableA VariableB VariableC VariableD VariableE
1    Name1        14        34        21       red       low
2    Name2        31        21      <NA>    yellow      high
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to do.  First is getting the text into a data frame.  I used `magrittr` pipe operators to make the process a little clearer, but it's essentially splitting by lines and then by colons.

```
library(magrittr)

my_d <- "RecordID:Name1
VariableA:14
VariableB: 34
VariableC: 21
VariableD:red
VariableE: low
RecordID: Name2
VariableA: 31
VariableB: 21
VariableD:yellow
VariableE:high" %>% 
strsplit("\n") %>%
unlist() %>%
strsplit(., ":") %>%
data.frame() %>%
t() %>% 
as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

rownames(my_d) <- 1:dim(my_d)[1]
colnames(my_d) <- c("colname", "value")
```

After that we have a data frame `my_d` with two columns.  Then we need to add a column specifying for each `VariableX`, which `RecordID` it belongs to...

```
my_d$is_RecordID <- my_d$colname == "RecordID"

runs <- rle(my_d$is_RecordID)
new_lengths <- runs$lengths %>% matrix(ncol=2) %>% apply(., 2, "sum")
new_values <- my_d$value[my_d$is_RecordID]

runs$lengths <- new_lengths
runs$values <- new_values
my_d$RecordID <- inverse.rle(runs)
```

Then reshape the "long" data frame into "wide" format.

```
my_d_long <- my_d[!my_d$is_RecordID, c("RecordID", "colname", "value")]
my_d_wide <- reshape(my_d_long, idvar = "RecordID", timevar = "colname", direction = "wide")
```